# Creating a new column based on several exiting columns

Tags: r

Hoping to create the new column D based on three existing columns: "A" "B" and "C". The dataset also have other variables E, F, G, etc.

Whenever A or B or C has a value, other two columns have NAs (E,F, G, not affected by them). The new variable "D" I need should import whatever the existing values from any of the A,B, or C columns.

```
 A    B     C       D    E  F  G
 1    NA    NA      1
 NA   2     NA      2
 NA   4     NA      4
 NA   NA    2       2
 NA   NA    3       3
```

Any simple codes within any packages that can do the trick? Thank you in advance!

I have seen other codes that can do the work but their datasets only have A,B and C, but my data set has other existing columns, so I need codes that can specify the A, B and C columns.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use `coalesce` on the 'A', 'B', 'C' to create the 'D' - `coalesce` will return the column with the first non-NA value per each row

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(D = coalesce(A, B, C), .after = 'C')
```

Comment: Thank you.  ".after = 'C' means the position of the D column, right? If i want D to appear at the end of the file, can be remove ".after = 'C'" ?

Comment: @Susan Yes, you can remove the `.after` as by default `mutate` creates a new column as the last column (if it was not existing)

Answer (score 2):

Update using `across`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(D = rowSums(across(A:C), na.rm = TRUE))
```

**OR**

We could use `mutate` with `rowSums`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(D = rowSums(.[1:3], na.rm = TRUE))
```

```
   A  B  C D E F G
1  1 NA NA 1 1 1 1
2 NA  2 NA 2 1 1 1
3 NA  4 NA 4 1 1 1
4 NA NA  2 2 1 1 1
5 NA NA  3 3 1 1 1
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), B = c(NA, 2L, 4L, NA, 
NA), C = c(NA, NA, NA, 2L, 3L), D = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L), E = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), F = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), G = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thanks! This code is very elegant. But I ran into an error message, any suggestions?  Can you see the codes below:      > AIexp %>%
+   mutate(man_hl = rowSums(c(con_man_hl, alg_man_hl, cha_man_hl, rob1_man_hl, rob2_man_hl)))
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `man_hl`.
x 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
ℹ Input `man_hl` is `rowSums(c(con_man_hl, alg_man_hl, cha_man_hl, rob1_man_hl, rob2_man_hl))`.
ℹ The error occurred in row 1.

Comment: Haha you read my mind; i was going to ask something about the contains or ends_with code in my case :)  I ran it, but another error message: > AIexp %>%   
+   mutate(man_hl = rowSums(contains("man_hl"), na.rm = TRUE))
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `man_hl`.
x `contains()` must be used within a *selecting* function.
ℹ See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-selection-context.html>.
ℹ Input `man_hl` is `rowSums(contains("man_hl"), na.rm = TRUE)`.
ℹ The error occurred in row 1.

Comment: Try: `AIexp %>% 
  mutate(man_hl = select(., contains("man_hl"), na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
  rowSums()`

Comment: Or this should work also: `AIexp %>% 
  mutate(man_hl = rowSums(select(., contains("man_hl")), na.rm=TRUE)) `

Comment: `AIexp %>% 
  mutate(man_hl = rowSums(across(contains("man_hl")), na.rm=TRUE)) `

Answer (score 2):

A base R way to do it is to use `pmax`:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                 B = c(NA, 2, 4, NA, NA),
                 C = c(NA, NA, NA, 2, 3))
```

Code:

```
df$D <- pmax(df$A, df$B, df$C, na.rm = TRUE)

# or

df$D <- with(df, pmax(A, B, C, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Output:

```
#    A  B  C D
# 1  1 NA NA 1
# 2 NA  2 NA 2
# 3 NA  4 NA 4
# 4 NA NA  2 2
# 5 NA NA  3 3
```